# Protractor chained tasks are timing out

Tags: angularjs, protractor

*I am running 2 protractor tests. Each run successfully within few secs.  Yet when I chain them the tests timeout although I raised the total time to 120000 msec. The first test runs a vanilla search with just a name.*

```
 it('use default setup and search for defendant named smith', function () {
    var results =  homePage.searchForDefendant('smith');
    expect(results == 299);
 });

it('expand search to adv options, and search for defendants', function () {

  homePage.getDefendantStartoverBtn().click();
  homePage.getDefendantName().sendKeys('smith,renee');
  homePage.getSearchOptions().click();  
  homePage.selectSexType('Female'); 
  homePage.selectRaceType('White');
  homePage.getDefendantDob().sendKeys('08/07/1970');
  homePage.getAdvSearchOptions().click();   
  homePage.selectDefendantCaseCounty('GUILFORD');

  homePage.getDefendantSearchBtn().click();
  var results = homePage.getDefendantSearchResults();
  expect(results == 1 );
});
```

*Both tests run successfully alone. I tried reversing the tests.. I still timeout.  Any help or pointer is appreciated.*

Comment: Do you have any `beforeEach()` blocks? If yes show them also.

Comment: I do not, but here is the start of the test:                                              var CiprsHomePage = require("./ciprs-home-page.js");

   describe('Test Defendant tab page', function() {
       
    var homePage = new CiprsHomePage();    
    // go to homepage
       homePage.get();
       
       browser.driver.sleep(500);
       
       // dismiss the disclaimer page
       homePage.dismissDisclaimerDialog();
       
       browser.driver.sleep(500);
       
       // navigate to defendant tab
       homePage.getDefendantTab().click();

Comment: I suggest you remove everything from the second test case, and add them back one at a time. I'm guessing your test cases are affecting the state of your app some how, which we have no knowledge over.